# Add Content-Type header to Very simple SimpleHTTPRequestHandler without extending the class

Tags: python, simplehttpserver, simplehttprequesthandler

I have an extremely simple http server setup for local testing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import partial
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import os

HTTP_DIR = os.getcwd()
SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map = {k: v + ';charset=UTF-8' for k, v in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map.items()}

test(HandlerClass=partial(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=HTTP_DIR), port=8000, bind='0.0.0.0')
```

I note that the `Content-Type` header is not sent for css files, and a little further digging indicated to me that it might be something to do with `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map` but as I understand it, [this only has overrides for the system mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) so I assumed that the System mappings should be automatically set?

> Changed in version 3.9: This dictionary is no longer filled with the default system mappings, but only contains overrides.

As I understand it, the system defaults should be added automatically, but the dump of `print(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map.items())` is this list:

```py
dict_items([('.gz', 'application/gzip;charset=UTF-8'), ('.Z', 'application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8'), ('.bz2', 'application/x-bzip2;charset=UTF-8'), ('.xz', 'application/x-xz;charset=UTF-8')])
```

I do see that I could [extend the functionality and add custom endpoints](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=watir%2Fnerodia%2Fnerodia-master%2Fnerodia%2Fsupport%2Fwebserver.py), but that would make the implementation more extensive than desired...

## EDIT

For some reason `.js` files *do* get `application/javascript`

Answer (score 0):

I added

`SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map['.css'] = 'text/css'`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from functools import partial
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, test
import os

HTTP_DIR = os.getcwd()
SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map = {k: v + ';charset=UTF-8' for k, v in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map.items()}

#Custom Content-type
SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.extensions_map['.css'] = 'text/css'
test(HandlerClass=partial(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, directory=HTTP_DIR), port=8000, bind='0.0.0.0')
```